# MongoError : Transaction 2 has been commited , Code : 256 , codeName : 'TransactionCommitted'

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am using mongoose and transaction I have caught upon this error which crash the nodejs server. I cannot find the error code in docs. [image: Error stack and I cant seem to find the error code or what the error means]

Answer (score 1):

That error comes from [here](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/r4.4.11/src/mongo/db/transaction_participant.cpp#L1690-L1693):

```
    // Cannot change committed transaction but allow retrying commitTransaction command.
    uassert(ErrorCodes::TransactionCommitted,
            str::stream() << "Transaction " << requestTxnNumber << " has been committed.",
            cmdName == "commitTransaction" || !o().txnState.isCommitted());
```

This is indicating that the transaction was already committed when an operation other than commitTransaction was received.